# XML resource accessed by URLRequest in as3 won't load if it is a local file

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, security, flash

This is my code:

```
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var xmlData:XML = new XML();

xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoadXML);
 this.url = url;
xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("C:\Documents and Settings\...books.xml"));

function LoadXML(e:Event):void {
    xmlData = new XML(e.target.data);
    trace(xmlData.author.text()[0]);
}
```

But it doesn't want to open the xml file, if I try with an online xml file it does, can someone tell me what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of security in sandbox mode, basically you can't do both: either you can check on your file system (and probably you don't execute flash inside a browser), or you access flash through an url which gives you access to web resources (with cross-domain security).

You can also add a special exception in flash manager in the url: http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html

But it is specific to your local settings, don't expect other users to have the same settings of course.

Comment: thanks can you tell me how I can change trace(xmlData.author.text()[0]); so between the [] a random number between 0 and 3 gets generated??

Comment: @user2852398 look at that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662219/actionscript-3-random-numbers-between-max-and-min

Comment: I think it schould be something like this: trace(xmlData.author.text()[0 + (3 - 0) * Math.random()]); but it doesn't work